# Data always gets truncated in SAS Proc Import (CSV)

Tags: string, csv, sas, truncation

I want to read in a bunch of CSV files. This one (movies_user.cleaned.csv) for example contains 2 variables: uid (user id) and movie_name. Because SAS only reads the first 20 rows for guessing the length of the string, my data gets truncated. ("Harry Potter" often changes to "Harry Pot" and so on.)

I know I can use guessingrows=32767 (32767 is the maximum that can be used) in my code to let SAS check the first 32767 rows, but I don't think this safe enough to ensure no truncation. Some of my CSV's are way bigger than this.

Here is the code I use:

```
proc import datafile="H:\FBDATA_CLEANED\facebookdata2\movies_user.cleaned.csv"
 out=thesis.activities2
 dbms=csv
 replace;
 getnames=yes;

run;
```

Can you guys help me out a bit? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Run `PROC IMPORT` manually.  In the log, you will see the `DATA STEP` code it generated.

Copy that code.

Replace `PROC IMPORT` with that `DATA STEP`.

Edit the size of the `INFORMAT` and `FORMAT` statements so the field is large enough.

Use the `DATA STEP` code going forward.

Comment: You can also open a new editor window after importing and press F4, which will recall the last code submitted.  Saves copying from the log and removing the line numbers

Comment: Agree, unless he's using Enterprise Guide, then you cannot.  Unless I've missed that feature (granted I don't use EG unless I have to).

Comment: I didn't know that, but I haven't used EG for about 8 years!

Comment: Hold down Shift key while selecting code in the log to avoid line numbers.

Comment: With this method, do you have to know beforehand how many bytes a variable needs to be?